# Transitions on max-height with relative units not working

Tags: css

I am trying to create a transition on max-height with a relative unit (so this CSS can be re-used anywhere).

I have added a POC below. The toggle button simply adds or removes a class which sets the max-height and has a transition. This example isn't working, but it is delayed by the transition duration (but only on removing the toggled class).

**So I wonder why:**

1. It isn't showing the animation. I know max-height needs a reference point. But a reference to what?
2. If you give everything a fixed unit: The animation will work, but only one way. Why is that?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('button').click(function() {
        $('div').toggleClass('collapsed');
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
}

div {
   border: solid 2px pink;
   max-height: 100%;
   transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 100px;
}

div.collapsed {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapsed"> 
Some text
</div>

<button>Toggle class</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Jquery you can easily use the `slideToggle` effect. remove the `collapse` class and add `display: none` to the `div` with a `height: 100px`

You can then use `slideToggle` in Jquery to toggle the display of the div element.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('button').click(function() {
       $('div').slideToggle('slow')
  });
});
```

```css
div {
   border: solid 2px pink;
   display: none;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
Some text
</div>

<button>Toggle class</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Kingsley, but the jQuery is just to have an example. In the application we only use CSS and JS. I am really trying to understand the issue on max-height transitions.